# php session directory permission deny

Tags: php, session, directory-permissions

I am new in php

this is login page script

```
<?php include('dbconnect.php');

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    $admins_sql = "SELECT * FROM  administrator WHERE   username = '" .$username. "' AND password = '".md5($password). "' AND status = 'Active'";
    $admin_exe = mysql_query($admins_sql, $con);

    //Setting session variable

    $admin_row=mysql_fetch_array($admin_exe);
    $_SESSION['username'] = $admin_row['username'];
    $_SESSION['type'] = $admin_row['type'];

    IF($_SESSION['type'] == 'Admin') {header("Location:admin");exit(); }
    IF($_SESSION['type'] == 'Main') {header("Location:main");  exit(); }
    IF($_SESSION['type'] == 'Teaching') {header("Location:Teaching"); exit(); }
    IF($_SESSION['type'] == 'Exam Cell') {header("Location:Exam Cell"); exit(); }
    IF($_SESSION['type'] == 'Non-Teaching') {header("Location:Non-Teaching"); exit(); }
    IF($_SESSION['type'] == 'Library') {header("Location:Library"); exit(); }
    IF($_SESSION['type'] == 'Main') {header("Location:office"); exit(); }
    IF($_SESSION['type'] == 'Placement') {header("Location:Placement"); exit(); }
    IF($_SESSION['type'] == 'Systems') {header("Location:CC"); exit(); }
    IF($_SESSION['type'] == 'student') {header("Location:student"); exit(); }

?>
```

have folders as seen in the redirects in the above script.

My problem is if a teaching type user logs in, they will be redirected to display url IP Address/main folder name/Teaching/index.php. They could just change Teaching in the url to admin, and then enter the admin folder and access the admin features.

What I want is for one type of user not to enter in another type of users folder.

Comment: on top of each area you can check the same way you are checking in your login page, but do not destroy your session, otherwise you will not be able to do such a validation.

Answer (score 0):

For example on top of your Main page, you should validate the access, and do the same for each area you have. There are other ways to do this, but this way should be ok for what you are looking for.

```
session_start();
if( !isset( $_SESSION['type'] ) AND $_SESSION['type'] != 'Main' ) {
    header("Location: AccessDenied");
}
```